# PHP Javascript cant access echoed element id outside php mode

Tags: javascript, php

Humble appologies if this is a stupid question but I cant for the life of me figure out what is wrong here.

I have an echoed element inside php mode:

```
echo'<select name="picks" id="winner">';
            echo'<option value="'.$row['team1'].'">'.$team1.'</option>';
            echo'<option value="'.$row['team2'].'">'.$team2.'</option>';
    echo'</select>';
```

Now ***outside*** php
I try to do a basic javascript GET:

```
document.getElementById("winner");
```

However the elemnt is not accessible am I missing something here, is it not possible to get echoed elements Ids?

Comment: Yes it is possible but what are you trying to do with that element ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "outside" php?

Comment: simply assign it to a variable and then do something basic like get its selected value

Comment: @JoshBjelovuk outside <?php mode ?>

Comment: if you just want to get the value of selected element you can use `onchange=function_name(this.value)` inside `select`

Comment: Are you doing it in <script> tag?

Comment: @vanadium23 offcourse

Comment: You wish to have the value of the selected item right?@Marilee

Comment: @Marilee please update you full code to make it clear

Comment: You see the element only after page is loaded. You should write your javascript code in `window.onload` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure your DOM has at least loaded before performing element selects. If you can use jQuery, then this is as easy as the following, and you can place this script in the `head` section, or anywhere in the `body`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Perform any selects on the DOM
});
```

**JS**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // The DOM is loaded and ready to be selected
    var select = document.getElementById("winner");
    var optionText = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
    var optionValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
});
</script>
```

Of course you can also perform DOM selects using jQuery:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // The DOM is loaded and ready to be selected
    var optionText = $("#winner option:selected").text();
    var optionValue = $("#winner option:selected").val();
});
</script>
```

---

**Another possibility**

If `$row`, `$team1` or `$team2` are not defined and you have PHP errors and notices turned on, then the HTML will render like so:

```
<select name="picks" id="winner"><b>E_NOTICE : </b> type 8 -- Undefined variable: row -- at line 4<br /><b>E_NOTICE : </b> type 8 -- Undefined variable: team1 -- at line 4<br />
    <option value=""></option><b>E_NOTICE : </b> type 8 -- Undefined variable: row -- at line 5<br /><b>E_NOTICE : </b> type 8 -- Undefined variable: team2 -- at line 5<br />
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
</select>
```

However, if you have PHP errors and warnings turned **off**, you would see something like this instead:

```
<select name="picks" id="winner">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="" selected></option>
</select>
```

If you are unable to access the value of options in your select HTML (because they are empty), this would be a good pace to start investigating.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQUERY you can try following:

```
// I have used mouse down event for demo purpose.
$(document).delegate('#winner', 'mousedown', function ()
{
  alert('hi');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the value of the selected id 
I am giving a demo fiddle
[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wk74qnbu/)
    `document.getElementById("winner").value;`

Answer (score 0):

Echoing JS codes is common but there are these possibilities:

1-You put `document.getElementById("winner");` before php creating that element.

2-There is a syntax error in script tag which cause error and there for your select does not work.

Answer (score 0):

since the php part will be available before page load you can simply do like this:

```
<?php 
$row['team1']=1;$team1='India';$row['team2']=2; $team2='SA';
echo'<select name="picks" id="winner">';
echo'<option value="'.$row['team1'].'">'.$team1.'</option>';
echo'<option value="'.$row['team2'].'">'.$team2.'</option>';
echo'</select>';
    ?>
<script>

console.log(document.getElementById("winner"));//see this in console.

</script>
```